# What goes on when using kinit with a keytab file

Tags: windows, java, active-directory, kerberos

Wish to get more understanding on the use of kinit and keytab file. For example, if I already have a keytab file generated for a service ( the service registered to active directory by `ktpass` `-mapuser` to `someuseraccount` )

```
ktab -k "mykeytab" -a <someprincipal>
```

what really happens under the hood when a user called `USERA` logs in to Windows and use this keytab as a input parameter for kinit?

```
kinit -k -t "mykeytab" <someprincipal>
```

Does the `kinit` generate initial credentials for `someprincipal`  or for the currently logged in `USERA` ?

Hope you can clear up this confusion of mine.
thanks